# Twisted Django Comet(Orbited): the interaction of upper and middle level

Tags: django, architecture, twisted

I'm developing a monitoring system(something like real-time web app). And the question is about system architecture. 
Device connects to server and sends information about controlled parameters state. Sever should save information to Database and notify Comet server. Comet server sends message to user saying that new data avaliable. User gets new information. 
What's the best way to analyze and save information(create alarm messages if needed) about device state:

1. Twisted app it self analyzes and interacts with DB(adbapi) and Comet server(Orbited).
2. Twisted pushes received data to Django(how to push?) and Django analyzes and saves data to DB and sends "NEW" flag to orbited.
3. Any Your suggestions, if there is a better way.

More information you can find on the pictures below:
[image: First architecture]
[image: Second architecture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is fairly open ended.  Someone could probably write a dozen pages on each of the options you described, and that much again on a handful of other approaches as a bonus.

Instead of doing that, I'll take an alternate route.

Make sure you have a good understanding of your requirements.  Think about which approach is going to be easiest for *you* (or for the developers on your team) to satisfy those requirements.  Take that approach, documenting the overall idea and unit testing everything you write (preferably using TDD).

When you're done, you might not have the optimal solution, but you'll have a solution, and 99 times out of 100 that's indistinguishable from being optimal.

If I do think about your proposed approaches a little bit, then what mostly occurs to me is that they don't differ from each other very much.  Your analysis is just some Python code somewhere that you're going to invoke.  Whether you invoke it closer to some Twisted-using code or closer to some Django-using code doesn't seem to make a *huge* difference to the outcome.  Perhaps some part of your requirements would make one approach better than the other.  However, if you have unit tests and understand your requirements, then I expect you'll actually find it quite easy to switch between those two approaches.

After you've implemented something, you'll have a much better understanding of the trade-offs involved and you'll be in a better position to decide if one implementation is going to work better or worse than another.

Note that unit tests are a pretty essential part of this idea.  Without them, you won't really know if you've implemented your requirements, you won't know if your functionality still works after any particular refactoring, and refactoring itself will be harder because your units will not be as well-defined and isolated as they would be if you were doing test-driven development.

Comment: Thank your for so full answer. I asked this question because I thought that there is a well-established solution(like better to use twisted app only for communication and other app for db interaction and vice versa). Your question told me that there is no "only right" way.